# How to align overflow ellipses horizontally for multiple divs that have equal widths?

Tags: html, css

[image: Example]

Hey all.
So I have an ngfor that is generating elements of equal width.
I'm using `text-overflow: ellipses`, but as the window is resized, the ellipses don't always stay in line with each other.
For example, on the photo above, these two overflowed words are both housed in equal-width labels, with identical padding and margins.
However, the overflow functionality seems to move as each letter is allowed space to be shown.

Why aren't the "..." always right-aligned to the div they're contained in?

Any help or tips is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Post your code here, so we can get a better understanding and you want to place the `"..."` like `Ho  ...` instead of `Ho...`

Comment: Why do you expect that they will be right-aligned? The text is left-aligned. The different text may be equal width but their individual characters certainly are not, and ellipses truncate full characters, not parts of characters. What you want isn't possible unless you right-align the text, use a fixed-width font, or create your own ellipses to place on top of the elements.